# <input type=file>の動作について

Tags: html5, asp.net, browser

VisualStudio2013 + ASP.NET MVC5でWebアプリケーションを開発しています。

`<input type=file>`を複数並べたWebページを作成し、ユーザーがローカルファイルを複数選択してアップロードできるように設計しました。
しかし、極稀に選択した一部のファイルが登録されない問題が発生しています。
テスト環境で確実に現象を出すことができないため、プログラム的な問題なのかブラウザの問題なのか、またはそれ以外の原因なのか切り分けができていません。

そこで質問なのですが、仮に、オペレーションミスでもプログラムの問題でもなかった場合、Webサーバーにアップロードされてくるべき一部のファイルがファイル単位で無くなってしまうという可能性はありますでしょうか？

＜補足＞
`<input type=file>`と書きましたが、正確には「Jasny Bootstrap」のコンポーネントを使用しています。
http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Comment: サーバ側で送信のフォームサイズに制限があるか、もしくはリクエストの時間切れじゃないのかな？端末側というよりサーバ側な気がします。失敗したファイルの共通点が無ければ、失敗時にどうなるのかもう少し詳しくあるといいかもしれません。

Comment: IISではコンテンツの最大長を2GBに設定しています。
リクエストの時間切れである可能性はあるかもしれません。
失敗したファイルの共通点はまだ分かっていません。
失敗というか、サーバー側にクライアントのローカルで指定されたファイルのストリームが送信されてきていない感じです。
3つファイルを指定されて2つしかサーバー側で登録されないという現象が極稀に発生しています。